# как применить merge

Tags: java, коллекции, merge

У мапы в качестве value выступает ArrayList, как при помощи .merge() добавить элементы в value мапы?
допустим мне нужно дополнить value у пары "three":list3. Чтобы было "three":["три"], а стало "three":["три"], ["что-то еще"]
что нужно вписать заместо arg2 и func в строке: map.merge("three", arg2  , (a, b)-> func);?

```
public class Test3 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Map<String, List<String>> map = new HashMap<>();

        List<String> list1 = new ArrayList<>();
        List<String> list2 = new ArrayList<>();
        List<String> list3 = new ArrayList<>();
        list1.add("один");
        list2.add("два");
        list3.add("три");

        map.put("one", list1);
        map.put("two", list2);
        map.put("three", list3);

  map.merge("three", arg2  , (a, b)-> func);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
List<String> arg2 = new ArrayList<>();
arg2.add("четыре");

map.merge("three", arg2, (a, b)-> {
    a.addAll(b);
    return a;
});
```

Comment: Спасибо, но так компилятор пишет ошибку: Bad return type in lambda expression: boolean cannot be converted to List<String>

Comment: @aberrate исправил.